# Is this a leaky integrator?

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-filters

We have implemented a way of approximating a data set with the following lines of code based on the *dx/dt* of [wikipedia of leaky integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_integrator).

```
dy = -A * y_previous + C   
y_current = y_previous + dy*delta_t
```

However, I am uncertain if we are allowed to call the following truly a leaky integrator. I was a bit confused how to get the general solution with Laplace transforms from the wikipage with this because of the `delta_t` in our implementation. I have to add that I am slightly familiar with Laplace, but not with z-transformations and I was told I needed this since it's discrete.

With `delta_t` being the difference in time between t_current and t_previous, which is a constant value. I think we may have created a leaky integrator due to `delta_t` being a constant, if I would for instance call `delta_t` [image: alpha] (alpha), `C` to `x_t`, and rewrite it a bit, it seems more similar to sources I found online ([1](http://www.claysturner.com/dsp/Leaky%20Integrator.pdf), [2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4699/how-does-this-equation-correspond-to-smoothing/4701#4701), [3](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/43851/is-there-a-common-name-for-the-first-order-iir-averaging-filter)):

[image: formula]

So then with the z-transform I have determined the transfer function:

[image: another]

My questions are:

1. Is in this case indeed the `delta_t` kind of [image: alpha] similar to the cited sites?
2. So is this indeed a leaky integrator?
3. What can I say about the values A and [image: alpha] can be for stability of the leaky integrator? Should indeed hold:

[image: A]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is indeed what is referred to as a “leaky integrator”, as the discrete time approximation of such a device. The key element that makes it “Leaky” is having the positive real pole at $z < 1$ which is the equivalent of a continuous time real pole along the negative real axis.

With the pole at $z=1$, (and a zero at $z=0$) we get the discrete time approximation of a pure integrator, this is an accumulator with the transfer function given as:

$$H(z) = \frac{z}{z-1}$$

Any other constants added are gain scaling, but this represents an “integrator” equivalent as the impulse invariant mapping of $H(s) = 1/s$.

As we move the pole off of $z=1$ As given by:

$$H(z) = \frac{z}{z-\alpha}$$

With $\alpha$ as an arbitrary real constant between 0 and 1 (not using OP’s $\alpha$ but generally), it becomes a “leaky integrator” with $\alpha$ as the damping factor: the closer $\alpha$ is to 1, the less the “leak”. Any other constant as before is just a scaling factor.

As noted, this is the discrete time equivalent to moving the pole on the s-plane from $s=0$ that we get with $H(s) = 1/s$ into the left half plane to be:

$$H(s) = \frac{1}{s+ 1/\tau}$$

Where $\tau$ is the time constant indicating a decay given by $e^{-t/\tau}$ which comes directly from the inverse Laplace Transform of $H(s)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate response! If I may ask another question, would it still be a leaky integrator if the `delta_t` was varying over t_1 to t_N, in other words not a constant?

Comment: Is your `delta_t` varying such that you don't have a consistent sample rate, or is it more that the sampling rate varies over the longer term duration? In either case changing `delta_t` simply changes $\alpha$ and similarly the time constant $\tau$, which just means the bandwidth or leak rate is modified accordingly-- but it is still a leaky integrator as long as the $\alpha$ you end up with has a value between 0 and 1 not including either.